# How do I use @section Scripts with child layout page in asp.net core 3.1 mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, layout-page

I have a master layout and then a child layout for certain views.

In the master layout, I have:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

The child layout references the master layout itself.

But I keep getting an exception on views where there are @section Scripts

The exception is:

InvalidOperationException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered by the page at *x*

*x* is the child layout page.

Surely the master layout should still render the script?

Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-5.0#specifying-a-layout) of Layout.`A layout can optionally reference one or more sections, by calling RenderSection. Sections provide a way to organize where certain page elements should be placed.`

If you use

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}
```

in your child layout,it means you can use  `@section Scripts`in your child layout.
And if you use

```
@{
        Layout = "_ChildLayout";
 }
```

in your other views,it means the layout is `_ChildLayout` rather than `_Layout` in the views.If you want to use  `@section Scripts`in the views,you need to add  `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)` to `_ChildLayout`,which is the layout of the views.